# Mirror API invalid_grant

Tags: google-api, google-glass, google-mirror-api

I'm trying to use Service Account on Mirror API to call a PHP script on my server to push card into Glass Timeline.

Actually I just get a JWT, but when I perform the POST Request to get my token, Google sends me:

```
> ' https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
{
  "error" : "invalid_grant"
}
```

I don't really know why. I use this line as Grant_type : `grant_type=urn%3Aietf%3Aparams%3Aoauth%3Agrant-type%3Ajwt-bearer`

If you get some information... Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use a service account to send data to the Mirror API.

Each call to the Mirror service requires it to be made on behalf of a specific user that has authorized you access to their Glass Timeline. You must use the access token generated by a specific user's oauth permissions to do so.

Google describes a service account as "an account that belongs to your application instead of to an individual end user", while each Glass is associated with a specific end-user account.

Comment: Arf, that what i was thinking... So bad. Thx for your answer

Comment: If you'd like, you may want to open up another question with more details about why you were trying this method and what you're hoping to do exactly.